Xamarin build error, old .NET project for iOS
Error:
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.302/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1248,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [/Users/estefanord/Downloads/Snap.Net-master/Mobile/Mobile.iOS/Snap.Net.Mobile.iOS.csproj]

Line 1248 of Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets:
<GetReferenceAssemblyPaths
        Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkMoniker)' != '' and ('$(_TargetFrameworkDirectories)' == '' or '$(_FullFrameworkReferenceAssemblyPaths)' == '')"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker='$(TargetFrameworkMoniker)'
        RootPath="$(TargetFrameworkRootPath)"
        TargetFrameworkFallbackSearchPaths="$(TargetFrameworkFallbackSearchPaths)"
        BypassFrameworkInstallChecks="$(BypassFrameworkInstallChecks)"
        ContinueOnError="!$(BuildingProject)">
      <Output TaskParameter="ReferenceAssemblyPaths" PropertyName="_TargetFrameworkDirectories"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="FullFrameworkReferenceAssemblyPaths" PropertyName="_FullFrameworkReferenceAssemblyPaths"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="TargetFrameworkMonikerDisplayName" PropertyName="TargetFrameworkMonikerDisplayName" Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkMonikerDisplayName)' == ''"/>
    </GetReferenceAssemblyPaths>

I have tried everything including reinstalling .NET, changing the product version and setting a path temporarily, but nothing seems to work to make this project work

exactly how old is this project?

approx 3 years: https://github.com/stijnvdb88/Snap.Net

Xamarin bits are deprecated, so there isn't much to discuss, if you don't migrate to .NET iOS.
